# What parameters play a role in the fluctuation of results during simulations?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, simulation

I have done many simulations under the null hypotheis to test the alpha level of a test which follows a normal distribution.
However, the results obtained vary by 2-3%, which seem to me a lot when trying to evaluate the alpha level. Sample size was 2000 individuals. (With 4000 individuals, results vary by 1-2%)

It seems to me that to get an idea of how much the result can vary, we calculate the fluctuation interval like this: $[p-1.96 * \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}; p+1.96 * \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}]$.

However, is the *n* that of the number of simulations I am doing?
Or the number of individuals in the simulated samples?

Instinctively, I would have thought that it is the number of simulations that has an effect on the stability of the result.

How to know the fluctuation interval of a result obtained with XX database simulations of YY individuals?

To add details, one of the tests evaluated has a Monte-Carlo variance with 1000 repetitions, and the other a bootstrapped variance (1000 repetitions).

Thank you very much in advance for the information on the subject.

Comment: Did you simulate from the null hypothesis?

Comment: Yes. I am under the null hypothesis but my nominal level is too high. Probably due to the effect of random parameters accross clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

The $n$ in the fluctuation interval is the number of simulations.

#### Background

The idea behind the fluctuation interval is quite simple:

- in every simulation, you count +1 when the test has rejected your null hypothesis. Otherwise, you don't count (+ 0). So, you keep a variable $S$ that initially is set to zero and gets incremented with each rejection of a null hypothesis.
- the simulations are independent of each other.
- as a result, the sum has a binomial distribution, $S\sim\text{Bin}(n, p)$, where $n$ is the number of simulations, and $p$ is the probability of actually rejecting the null hypothesis.

For large $n$, like the $n=1000$ simulations, you can safely approximate the binomial distribution with a normal distribution, and assume
$ S\sim \text{N}(np, np(1-p)).$

Now, you are not really interested in the sum $S$, but in your estimator for the rejection probability, which is $\hat{p}=S/n$. This has, in good approximation, a normal distribution:
$$
\hat{p}\sim \text{N}(p, p(1-p)/n).
$$
That normal distribution implies that about 95% of all outcomes for $\hat{p}$ would lie within the fluctuation interval:
$$
\text{Prob}\big(p - 1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}\leq \hat{p}\leq p + 1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n} \big) = 0.95.
$$

##### Length of fluctuation interval

The length of the fluctuation interval depends both on the number $n$ of simulations and on the true probability $p$. This probability, in turn, depends on the nominal level $\alpha$ of the test, and on the sample size, when the simulations are from an alternative model (not the null hypothesis), and on a possibly wrong size of the test (size of test = true rejection probability under the null hypothesis).

##### Tacit independence assumption

The fluctuation interval is based on the assumption that the simulation results are *independent*. This is not always the case; for example, when the simulation uses MCMC output from one chain. Then the results can be positively correlated. In such cases, the $n$ in the formula for the interval should be corrected and replaced by the effective number of simulations $n_{\text{eff}}$, if available. When there is positive correlation, $n_{\text{eff}}$ is smaller than $n$, and the fluctuation interval using the actual number of simulations would be too optimistically short in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so if I make 500 simulations, I can expect, if the test has a correct nominal risk to find a result within the following interval: [0.05-1.96*sqrt(0.05*0.95/500); 0.05+1.96*sqrt(0.05*0.95/500) that is [3.1%; 6.9%] ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)